# Will a sufficiently compressed electric charge eventually collapse?

Tags: gravity, charge, mass-energy

It takes energy to compress an electric charge into a space.  This is the basis for the classical electron radius formula.  We also know that energy creates gravitation.  Does it stand to reason that if you compress an electric charge sufficiently the gravitational force generated from that energy will overpower the repulsion?  If so will this cause the charge to collapse forever?  Will this be true even if it's too light to form a blackhole?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no accepted quantum theory of gravity, we'll answer this in the classical limit of a uniform sphere. The answers to "[If we compress a large amount of charge into a very small region, what will happen? Will it become something similar to that of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528156/145491)", may also be helpful.

The (repulsive) [electrostatic potential energy](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_08.html) and (attractive) [gravitational potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55487/145491) of a solid sphere of radius $R$ with uniform charge and mass density are
$$U_E=\frac{3}{5}\frac{Q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}=\frac{3}{5} Z^2  \frac{\alpha}{R} \hbar c, \qquad U_G=-\frac{3}{5}G\frac{M^2}{R}$$
where $Q=Ze$ and $M$ are the total charge and mass of the sphere, $e$ is the [elementary charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge), and $\alpha$ is the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant). If we ignore the rest masses of the charges in the sphere, its electrostatic mass will be $M_E=U_E/c^2$, so the corresponding gravitational potential energy will be

$$U_G=-\frac{3}{5}G\frac{M_E^2}{R} = \frac{3^3}{5^3} G Z^4  \frac{\alpha^2  }{R^3}\frac{\hbar^2}{c^2}$$

The sphere will collapse if $U_E<-U_G$, i.e. if

$$ R < \frac{3}{5}  Z  \sqrt{\alpha}  \sqrt{G\frac{\hbar}{c^3}} \,\approx\,0.05\,Z\,L_P$$

where $L_P=1.616 \times 10^{-35}$ m is the [Planck Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_length).

This estimate is completely untrustworthy for small $Z$, since Planck scale calculations would require understanding quantum gravity, but might conceivably be relevant at astrophysical scales.

Interstellar dust can be ionized by radiation, and [according to one calculation](https://doi.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/8/1/002) interstellar clouds of charged dust could be supported against gravitational collapse by their electrostatic repulsion, but the analysis is very different since the electrostatic "mass" is negligible compared to the actual dust mass, and temperature is very important. In our discussion above, we did not consider what the charge actually consisted of, and whether the charge "gas" would heat up as it was compressed.